# Pine script - plot only once after buy condition is met

Tags: pine-script

I have a pine script that plots flag shape when a target is met after a buy condition. The problem is it plots every subsequent target for the same buy condition. Does anyone have a script that would plot a target only once for that particular buy condition?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store condition for plotting in some `var` variable:

```
var plot_condition = 0
plot_condition := 0

if buy_condition
    ....
    plot_condition := 1

plot(plot_condition? data : na, style = shape.xcross)
```

Comment: Thanks Starr Lucky for responding....  


Below are the parameters I have for my script...can you guide how i can use the code you mentioned above to utilize these parameters?

Buy_Condition = RSI < 20
, target = Buy_Condition ? high + 50 : na
, Plot_Condition = high > target (this is any candle that first crosses the target)

Comment: This did not work, it still plots target multiple times